# MySQL Select results which do not contain words from another select

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like:

-----TABLE1----

1.out_name

2.out_name_log

3.out_name2

4.out_name2_log   -

5.out_name3

6.out_name3_log

7.out_name4

8.out_name4_log

---

and

---TABLE2----

1.name2     -

2.name3     -

---

I want to select data from TABLE1 if they do not contain any words from TABLE2.

I want the result to show:

out_name

out_name_log

out_name4

out_name4_log

Comment: Is there no scope to normalise your data?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select data from a column that are not in another table.
You can use `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`s.

```
  SELECT TABLE1.*
    FROM
    TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.`col1`=TABLE2.`col1`
    WHERE TABLE2.`col1` IS NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: With your answer as you said I get all data from table one not in table two.
What I am looking for is data in the first table that do not contain any words from the second table (example:out_name_log does not contain either name2 or name3 but out_name2 contain name2 in it).

Comment: If you can set up an sql fiddle for your data, i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a dynamic sql query to achieve this. But this might be a bad solution if `TABLE2` having more number of rows.

**Query**

```
set @query = null;
select
group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'col1 not like ''%',col1,'%'' and '
    ) separator ' '
  ) into @query
from TABLE2 ;

set @query = left(@query,length(@query) - 4);
set @query = concat('select * from TABLE1 where ', @query);

prepare stmt from @query;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a18b/1)